# Добавление в таблицу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть список друзей в json.

```
"friends": [
        {
            "steamid": "76561198015673172",
            "relationship": "friend",
            "friend_since": 1500131828
        },
        {
            "steamid": "76561198032830606",
            "relationship": "friend",
            "friend_since": 1495349532
        },
```

Делаю запрос для добавления их в таблицу, в таблицу вводиться undefined, что не так?

```
$.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://project-megaroks931128.codeanyapp.com/users/add/?usersid=" + UserId,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var friends = $('#friends');
            var friend;
            for (var prop in data.friends) {
                friend += '<tr class="row">' + '<td class="cell" id="friends-avatar">' + data.friends.steamid + '</td>' + '<td class="cell" id="relationship">' + data.friends.relationship + '</td>' + '<td class="cell" id="friend_since">' + data.friends.friend_since + '</td>' + '</tr>';
                friends.append(friend);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли указать ключ -  `data.friends[prop]`

```js
const friends = [
        {
            "steamid": "76561198015673172",
            "relationship": "friend",
            "friend_since": 1500131828
        },
        {
            "steamid": "76561198032830606",
            "relationship": "friend",
            "friend_since": 1495349532
        }
];


var friend = ''; // Первый undefined был тут. Начнайте с пустой строки
for (var prop in friends) { // Prop это не prop, а номер друга в массиве
     friend += '<tr class="row">' + '<td class="cell" id="friends-avatar">' + friends[prop].steamid + '</td>' + '<td class="cell" id="relationship">' + friends[prop].relationship + '</td>' + '<td class="cell" id="friend_since">' + friends[prop].friend_since + '</td>' + '</tr>';
     // Вы зачем-то каждую итерацию добавляете в таблицу 
     // всех друзей от первого до текущего.
     // friends.append(friend); 
}     
console.log(friend);


// Как я бы это сделал:
console.log(friends.map(friend => `
<tr class="row">
    <td class="cell" id="friends-avatar">${friend.steamid}</td>
    <td class="cell" id="relationship">${friend.relationship}</td>
    <td class="cell" id="friend_since">${friend.friend_since}</td>
</tr>`
).join(''));
```

PS: вы в курсе, что элементов с одинаковыми id быть не должно? лучше положите ваши `id` у `td` в `class`

Comment: Спасибо, я понял свои ошибки. id убрал, добавил class